# Answers being progressive rewritten until they are right. Is that OK?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits, fastest-gun

I noticed this ethically questionable activity. There is a question, 3-4 mediocre answers pop up (20, 40 and 60 % correct/complete ), I provide an answer too. For the sake of example ..let's say that my answer is relatively the most comprehensive (90 % completeness). However, on of the "competitors" whose answer was lousy at first,  quickly take cues from mine, rewrites his answer 2-4 times so eventually he ends up with the most comprehensive answer.

The OP comes 20 mins after this and he rewards the know how thief.

How can I protect my investment (time, effort & know how) to receive the reputation points in cases like this?

Comment: This sounds like a rant, and there is really nothing you can do about it (as the answers also note), or even prove that its happening.

Comment: No it is not a rant. It is a perfectly calm (I know because I am asking it in my head, trust me) rational question. Try simply read it like that please.

Comment: It is pretty horrible to see some people come in and post horribly vague/incorrect answers, then copy the specifics from later answers. You can always edit your answer to be more comprehensive than theirs, though.

Comment: I cannot prove it but circumstantial evidence points to that. All three answers had one missing piece for 15 mins. Once I provided an answer, the missing piece miraculously showed up in 2 other answers in like 1-2 mins. I literally saw it propagate though them :)

Comment: @EarlGrey I'm not saying it *doesn't* happen, just that you can't prove it. But asking how you can "protect" your answer seems a silly question, its public information, there is *clearly* nothing you can do to "protect" it. You are free to DV the other answers of course.

Comment: Yeah it is kind of a duplicate. I did of course a check for duplicates but I used words that did not indicate it was asked. however one wonders how the same question can have -4 vs 18 votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely nothing indicates that they stole from you rather than adding information they knew themselves already.

This is the "[Fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)". If you can't deal with that, then you should focus on questions that are already a bit older and don't attract these people.

Personally I hate it as well and any answer that is less than 80% from what I want it to be receives a downvote and it's very unlikely I will change that vote once the answer has become acceptable.

In short: nothing to do about it except accept it and perhaps have some petty revenge.

Comment: This recently happened in an answer that you made 10 seconds before my post, and I felt discouraged about not receiving more points. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290458/changing-a-fast-incorrect-answer-to-match-a-slower-correct-answer

Answer (score 3):

I think the aim of the site is to provide comprehensible and well written answers

if OP chooses another answer over yours then probably the answer provided is shorter or more comphrensible

but on the other end, if you answer is better and if the question has enough attention,
your answer should float to the top of the answers list and then be chosen by OP

the problem could be that the question has not enough attention or that viewers are using their votes sparely

also it is possible that they provided an answer at first, and then refined it, because they saw it was missing something, without your intervention

I personally refine my answers and questions over and over,
that means someone who writes the same information simultaneously might as well think I'm stealing from them, but in reality I haven't even seen it

Comment: That happens to me too. I wonder if they think I steal from them too. In reality I don't. But sometimes, you realize you need to add things to your answer to make it more useful. Once or twice, I added information to my answer as a result of my search. Sometimes 10 min later.