# Making a wholesale change to a fast, incorrect, accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request

## Scenario

I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662581/how-can-i-programmatically-do-method-overload-resolution-in-c) in which the following took place:

1. Person (x) answered more quickly but incorrectly.
2. That answer was accepted.
3. Moments later person (y) answered correctly.
4. Person (x) changed his answer by deleting 1477 characters (first [997](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29662988/4) then [480](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29662988/5).)

This has some problems in the StackOverflow token economy:

- I was person (y) and felt cheated out of points that I had earned.
- This encourages hasty, somewhat helpful, but ultimately incorrect answers.

This seems like a way to game the system. We post a rushed but incorrect answer, somehow it gets marked as correct, and then we do a wholesale edit (perhaps based on other, more accurate answers.)

## Feature Request

Once an answer is accepted, only 10% of the content can change, after which the system prevents further edits.

The would help because,

1. the person who asked the question might realize that the answer is incorrect and thereby award the "accept" to the actual, correct answer.
2. even if that doesn't happen, the community might realize that the accepted answer is incorrect and down vote it while up voting the actual, correct answer.

## Re Duplicate

The answer in the duplicate says:

> Absolutely nothing indicates that they [did x] rather than adding information they knew themselves already.

In the scenario about which I'm talking, person (x) deleted 1477 characters. This does not indicate adding information they knew themselves already.

Comment: It's particularly ironic that the accepted answerer of [Answers being progressive rewritten until they are right. Is that OK?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285686/answers-being-progressive-rewritten-until-they-are-right-is-that-ok) seems to be the person OP is complaining about.

Comment: 10%? I edit my answers a lot.. not with someone else's answer, but with important links, extra content, new finds, statistics. Also, if the OP doesn't understand your answer you sometimes have to expand on it with "edits".

Comment: @tux3 outstanding...

Comment: @tux3 That is ironic.

Comment: I'm surprised by all the down votes of this question. I'd like to understand what I'm missing. Suggestions?

Comment: On "feature request" questions on meta, a downvote often indicates people don't like the feature request, not that there's a problem with the question itself.

Comment: re: `10%`  Noooooo.  I sometimes post one version to succinctly answer the OP's question,  Later (days, weeks not minutes), if it is the right kind of question/topic, I might expand the answer making it a bit broader with whys, wherefores, how-tos and references to make it more helpful to a broader audience.

Comment: I remember that post, the first version was rather troubled.  Regardless, he can't be held hostage to a quick answer mark by a rather confused questioner.  That was not his mistake.

Comment: I removed my answer because of the constant flow of messages and changing of my words in my answer. To sum up: yes, apparently you had the best solution first. I was unaware of this. The solution I posted worked as well. After being notified of this, I changed my answer to reflect the shorter solution. After another possible inaccuracy I made it a Community Wiki since it weren't my words anymore. At no point did I intend to be the fastest gun in the west and my overall attitude on SO should make that clear. I have requested a deletion so your more complete answer can be accepted.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The changing of the words in your answer was done because the words in your answer were incorrect. I'm glad you deleted it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I admire your willingness to request a deletion.

Comment: @HansPassant He wasn't held hostage by a quick answer mark. He was held hostage by posting an incorrect answer in the first place.

Comment: Well, I'd have to recommend twenty whiplashes then to make sure he never does that again.  Snap!

Comment: @HansPassant Done. This dialog represents the whiplashes (or petty revenge on my part,) and that's what [he'd recommend too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285688/1108891).

Answer (score 13):

> Once an answer is accepted, only 10% of the content can change, after which the system prevents further edits.

This is not a good idea. People searching for answers don't care who got points, they care that they can find a solution to their problem.

Comment: That's fair. At the same time, people answering questions do care who gets points. We need to motivate the both the people who provide and who consume the answers.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yes, but we need to do that without sacrificing what we're here for. We're creating a repository of programming knowledge. If you don't get all the points for your contributions, so be it. The accepted answer being up-to-date and accurate is more important.

Comment: Of course you're right. I'm afraid that's emotionally hard for me, because I believe that effort *should* be awarded. That's a big should, though, and realistic thinking understands that life isn't always going to be fair and just.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Sure, but the number of times someone steals an answer is tiny compared to the number of times an author needs to legitimately update their answer significantly. Your proposed change would be too restricitve.

Comment: That's also fair. I think the best thing for me to do is cognitive therapy on myself :-). "Life isn't fair, and I can handle that."